# How can I stream .mp3 files in Java?

Tags: java, spring, mp3, audio-streaming

I want to stream mp3 files and accessing them using spring, but i dont know how :( have already searched the internet but havent found anything yet. I already tried it using Streams and it worked kinda, but every song starts at the beginning and other people also start at the beginning of the song. My code:
Backend:

```
new Thread(() -> {
            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while(true){
                try {
                    currentSong = files[rd.nextInt(files.length-1)];
                    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(currentSong));
                    int read = 0;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    while((read = is.read(bytes)) !=-1){
                            stream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }
                    stream.flush();
                    is.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();;
```

Frontend:

```
public class DnBController {

    @GetMapping("/dnb")
    public String play(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {

        OutputStream os = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("audio/mpeg");
        DnbradioApplication.stream.writeTo(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
        return "site.html";
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "stream", and how you think Spring might help you?

Comment: Sure. So I have some mp3 files which i want to "stream" like a radio station. I have the Backend where i read those mp3 files as a stream and try to route them to the GET-method from spring. So when i open the site, the mp3 starts playing. It kinda works, but the song always starts at the beginning and the songs are not playing like on a real radio "step by step" if you know what i mean

Comment: I see. Before you can even start on writing code for this, you're going to need to explore how such features work at the HTTP level. In particular, you'll want to look into splitting into parts (not necessary, but commonly used) and HTTP Partial Content.

Comment: Okay, ill have a look. Thank you :)